# Java project: Property file from resource directory is not accessible

Tags: java, spring, jersey

I am building a jersey-2 webapp. I can't access config.property file from resource. What am I missing?

```
@Bean(name = com.tarkshala.photo.drive.Configuration.CONFIGURATION_BEAN_NAME)
public Properties getConfiguration() throws IOException {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
    properties.load(input);
    return properties;
}
```

[image]

Bean initialization fails with following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.tarkshala.photo.spring.SpringAppConfig.getConfiguration(SpringAppConfig.java:47)
    at com.tarkshala.photo.spring.SpringAppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3ecfb6f6.CGLIB$getConfiguration$5(<generated>)
    at com.tarkshala.photo.spring.SpringAppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3ecfb6f6$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$45328ae1.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try YourCurrentClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties")

Comment: “While this code may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that when using the getResourceAsStream on a ClassLoader instance, the path is treated as absolute starting from the root of the classpath. [reading-file-in-java](https://www.baeldung.com/reading-file-in-java)

```
public InputStream getResourceFileAsInputStream(String fileName) {
    ClassLoader classloader = SpringAppConfig.class.getClassLoader();
    return classloader.getResourceAsStream(fileName);   
}

public Properties getConfiguration() throws IOException {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    InputStream input = getResourceFileAsInputStream("config.properties");
    properties.load(input);

    return properties;
}
```

[java-properties-file-examples](https://mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/)